# Evaluating INDIRECT in an array in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a linear regression function that dynamically references columns, can handle `#N/A` values, and will function as additional rows are added over time. Here is a sample dataset:

```
Date        Value 1 Value 2
1/2/1991    #N/A    #N/A
2/4/2002    276.36  346.31
1/7/2003    252     350
1/21/2004   232     345.5
1/6/2005    257     368
2/1/2006    278.24  390.11
2/23/2007   #N/A    380.46
2/11/2008   326.34  383.04
2/12/2009   #N/A    399.9
2/17/2009   334.39  #N/A
1/29/2010   344.24  400.83
1/27/2011   342.88  404.52
2/7/2012    379     417.91
1/23/2013   #N/A    433.35
```

Here is the function that I've developed so far, based on [this forum post](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/677162-how-do-i-ignore-n-linest-i-have-partial-solution-already.html).  It calculates the linear regression for Value 1.

```
=TRANSPOSE(
  LINEST(
    N(
      OFFSET(
        INDIRECT("B2" & ":B" & COUNTA(B:B)),
          SMALL(
            IF(
              ISNUMBER(
                INDIRECT("A2:A" & COUNTA($A:$A)) *
                INDIRECT("B2" & ":B" & COUNTA(B:B))),
              ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B" & COUNTA(B:B))) - ROW(B2)),
            ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & MIN(
              COUNT(INDIRECT("A2:A" & COUNTA($A:$A))),
              COUNT(INDIRECT("B2:B" & COUNTA(B:B))))))), 0, 1)),
    N(
      OFFSET(
        INDIRECT("A2:A" & COUNTA($A:$A)),
          SMALL(
            IF(
              ISNUMBER(
                INDIRECT("A2:A" & COUNTA($A:$A)) *
                INDIRECT("B2:B" & COUNTA(B:B))),
              ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B" & COUNTA(B:B))) - ROW(B2)),
            ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & MIN(
              COUNT(INDIRECT("A2:A" & COUNTA($A:$A))),
              COUNT(INDIRECT("B2:B" & COUNTA(B:B))))))), 0, 1)),
    TRUE, FALSE))
```

With the way it is currently written, dragging my array to the right to solve for Value 2 requires some manual updating of the formula.  Everything in quotes in the `INDIRECT` formulas must be manually changed from `B` to `C`.  I have 40 columns of data, though, so I tried to make the formula entirely dynamic using `ADDRESS`, `ROW`, and `COLUMN`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(
  LINEST(
    N(
      OFFSET(
        INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN(B2)) & ":" & ADDRESS(COUNTA(B:B), COLUMN(B2))),
        SMALL(
          IF(
            ISNUMBER(
              INDIRECT("A2:A" & COUNTA($A:$A)) *
              INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN(B2)) & ":" & ADDRESS(COUNTA(B:B), COLUMN(B2)))),
            ROW(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN(B2)) & ":" & ADDRESS(COUNTA(B:B), COLUMN(B2)))) - ROW(B2)),
          ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & MIN(
            COUNT(INDIRECT("A2:A" & COUNTA($A:$A))),
            COUNT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN(B2)) & ":" & ADDRESS(COUNTA(B:B), COLUMN(B2)))))))), 0, 1)),
    N(
      OFFSET(
        INDIRECT("A2:A" & COUNTA($A:$A)),
          SMALL(
            IF(
              ISNUMBER(
                INDIRECT("A2:A" & COUNTA($A:$A)) *
                INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN(B2)) & ":" & ADDRESS(COUNTA(B:B), COLUMN(B2)))),
              ROW(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN(B2)) & ":" & ADDRESS(COUNTA(B:B), COLUMN(B2)))) - ROW(B2)),
            ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & MIN(
              COUNT(INDIRECT("A2:A" & COUNTA($A:$A))),
              COUNT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN(B2)) & ":" & ADDRESS(COUNTA(B:B), COLUMN(B2)))))))), 0, 1)),
    TRUE, FALSE))
```

This gives me `#REF!`.  When I do a step-by-step evaluation of the formula, it looks like the issue comes when Excel evaluates `COLUMN`.  It introduces braces to the formula, which propagate through the rest of the `INDIRECT` evaluation.  Here is a quick comparison:

**Original formula:**

```
INDIRECT("B2:B15")
```

**Dynamic formula:**

```
INDIRECT({"$B$2:$B$15"})
```

This evaluates as `#VALUE`, and at that point the rest of the formula is broken.  Is there a way to force Excel to not use braces in this evaluation, or is there a better way of making this calculation?

Comment: So the end purpose is to make the first formula *'column relative'* so it can be dragged to the right and all column references within the quoted strings will shift while leaving the absolute column references like $A:$A alone?

Comment: Would the correct result for column C (e.g. *Value 2*) be 0.0207852803175708?

Comment: @Jeeped that is correct on both accounts.

Comment: All answers are good imho. Another option which could be extended to polynomials if required is: `=LINEST(IFERROR(B2:B15,),ISNUMBER(B2:B15)*A2:A15^{0,1},0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you only trying to get the `SLOPE` from the linear regression?  If so, you can just use the `SLOPE` function after converting the `#N/A` to blanks (using `IFERROR` in a formula).  `SLOPE` will then just toss out the blanks.  If you want the intercept as well, use the same formulas below and substitute `INTERCEPT` for `SLOPE`.

**Picture of ranges**

[image: picture]

**Formulas** are array formulas (use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) and copied over. Given this arrangement, the simple formula (non-dyanmic) would be:

```
=SLOPE(IFERROR(B2:B15,""),$A$2:$A$15)
```

If you want these to be dynamic, you can use `INDEX` and `COUNTA` to get the dynamic range.

```
=SLOPE(IFERROR(B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),""),$A$2:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)))
```

**Use a `Table` instead**

Even better, you could define this data inside a `Table` and then use the headers to pull in the whole column.  That formula would look nice and copy easily.

[image: table instead]

Still using an array formula here, but the only variable is the column heading which is used to look into the `Table1`.  This one would be more resistant to blanks in the data which will break the `COUNTA` used above.

```
=SLOPE(IFERROR(INDEX(Table1,,MATCH(M1,Table1[#Headers])),""),Table1[Date])
```

Comment: This does solve for slope, but I'd prefer to also have the intercept.  It seems to work with the #N/A values still in there; I'm not sure where you wanted those converted to blanks.

Comment: To get intercept, copy the formula and use `INTERCEPT` instead of `SLOPE`.

Comment: Regarding `#N/A`, my understanding is you want to **exclude** them from the analysis? If so, using `IFERROR` forces the `#N/A` to a `""` which is then ignored/excluded by `SLOPE/INTERCEPT`.  By exclude, I mean: the corresponding x-value for the `#N/A` is removed from the analysis as though the data point was completely missing.  No conversion is needed, I was just explaining how the formulas works in the answer.

Comment: Ok. `SLOPE` `INTERCEPT` and `CORREL` are generally easier to use for simple linear regression than `LINEST`.  If you start needing polynomials then you can't use them, but for linear cases they are great.  You also won't get the answer as an array with those three, but I generally prefer that so I can put the values wherever I want.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you can use the following, shorter, non-volatile **array formula****:

`=LINEST(INDEX(B:B,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(B2:B15),{1,1}*ROW(B2:B15)))))),INDEX($A:$A,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(B2:B15),{1,1}*ROW(B2:B15)))))))`

B2:B15 can be dynamically defined if desired as per Jeeped's solution.

Regards

Comment: This is much simpler than what I had originally come up with.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to get rid of the use of the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) as much as possible; certainly as it pertains to substituting column references for string equivalents. It seems that many can be replaced with a form of [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pairs.

```
=TRANSPOSE(
  LINEST(
    N(
      OFFSET(B2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A )),
          SMALL(
            IF(
              ISNUMBER(
                $A2:INDEX($A:$A, MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A )) *
                B2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A ))),
              ROW(B2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A ))) - ROW(B2)),
            ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & MIN(
              COUNT($A2:INDEX($A:$A, MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A ))),
              COUNT(B2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A ))))))), 0, 1)),
    N(
      OFFSET(
        $A2:INDEX($A:$A, MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A )),
          SMALL(
            IF(
              ISNUMBER(
                $A2:INDEX($A:$A, MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A )) *
                B2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A ))),
              ROW(B2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A ))) - ROW(B2)),
            ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & MIN(
              COUNT($A2:INDEX($A:$A, MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A ))),
              COUNT(B2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A ))))))), 0, 1)),
    TRUE, FALSE))
```

Fill right as necessary and have column A locked while column B cell range references will shift to column C, D, etc.

[image: Replacing INDIRECT with INDEX]

Further function replacement could likely exchange at least some of the [OFFSET functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) use for an appropriate INDEX function but the formula seems to work well as it is now.